# How to create a custom shortcode based on the layout?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-query, shortcode

Hi I am developing a custom post type plugins. Which has shortcode support. Already i have created a shortcode which is going to use for default layout design. Again i have to create a onemore shortcode  for another layout design.

My current shortcode **[testimonial]**

i want the shortcode something like this **[testimonial style="fancy"]**. How can i do it.can any one suggest me .

Thanks

Comment: CPT with shortcode doesn't really match. What exactly are you trying to do? What does testimonial shortcode do? Please explain more.

Comment: created a CPT testimonial plugin . when i use [testimonial] shortcode it displays default layout design option . i have couple of designs so when i use [testimonial style="fancy"] it need to display another layout design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture the attributes that passed to a shortcode. You can do that like this

```
add_shortcode('testimonial', 'testimonial_shortcode_func');
function testimonial_shortcode_func( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
      'style' => 'default_value_if_no_value_is_provided',
    ), $atts );

    if( $atts['style'] == 'fancy' ) {
        //do something
    } else if ( $atts['style'] == 'something_else' ) {
        //do something
    }
    //And so on
    //finally return content, don't echo just return
}
```